# Is there a Python function to repeat string patterns to get faster multiple columns in different dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm new in Python, I need to get many variables in multiple dataframes:

I wrote this code but I need a long time to configure it for many excersises.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([df1[df1.columns[0]], df2[df1.columns[0]], df1[df1.columns[1]],
                df2[df1.columns[1]], df1[df1.columns[2]], df2[df1.columns[2]],
                df1[df1.columns[3]], df2[df1.columns[3]], df1[df1.columns[4]],
                df2[df1.columns[4]], df1[df1.columns[5]], df2[df1.columns[5]],
                df1[df1.columns[6]], df2[df1.columns[6]]], axis=1)
```

The number of dataframes and columns can be much bigger. Thanks.

Comment: What I have done is to write a simple program to create the text you need.

Comment: A program in Python? How?

Comment: Please specify your input and desired output

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to do is: for all of the columns in one dataframe, combine the columns from that dataframe with those from another with the same columns, into a single dataframe with two of every column in the same original order.

In your case:

```
df1 = DataFrame([['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f']])
df2 = DataFrame([['g','h','i'], ['j','k','l']])

df = concat([s for ss in [(df1[c], df2[c]) for c in df1.columns] for s in ss], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   0  0  1  1  2  2
0  a  g  b  h  c  i
1  d  j  e  k  f  l
```